# SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' - first line

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

I’m using CodeIgniter framework and I want to make a chained drop-down with JavaScript code. Then I get this error:

`SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' //first line`

But my first line is `<!DOCTYPE html>` and my file type is PHP not JavaScript, here is my JavaScript code:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label for="inputBody">Body Number</label>
                <select name="inputBody" id="inputBody" onchange="javascrip: ambildata(this.value);" class="form-control" required="required">
                   <?php foreach ($body as $bd) { ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $bd->bodynumkids ?>" ><?php echo $bd->bodynumkids ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                  </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <label for="inputKiddie">Kiddies Name</label>
                  <!-- <div class="form-label-group"> -->
                    <input type="text" name="inputKiddie" id="inputKiddie" class="form-control" placeholder="ex. Super Cop" required="required">
                  <!-- </div> -->
                </div>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                  function ambildata(x) {
                    $.ajax({
                      type:'POST',
                      url :'<?php echo base_url("Repairpaint/chained"); ?>',
                      jsonp : 'callback',
                      dataType: 'jsonp',
                      data :{ '#inputBody' : x},
                      success: function(response){
                        console.log(response);
                        var len = response.length;
                        if(len > 0){
                          var tampil = response[0].namakids;
                          $('#inputKiddie').text(tampil);
                        } else {
                          $('#inputKiddie').text('wek');
                        }
                      }
                    })
                  }
                </script>
              </div>
            </div>
```

And here the controller :

```
public function chained()
    {
        $dataKiddie = $this->input->post('inputBody');
        $where = array('bodynumkids'=> $dataKiddie);
        $response = $this->Model_repairpaint->chaincb('kiddiejadi', $where)->result();
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
```

I have searched similar questions and solutions around Stack Overflow but I found nothing. Can anyone help me find out the solution?

Comment: most likely, the JSONP request returns with something other than javascript - perhaps you're sending JSONP wrong (from the server)

Comment: of course we would need to see an example of what your `chained()` function outputs

Comment: Do you get this error on browser's console?

Comment: @SujeetAgrahari yes, I got it from the browser console

Comment: Try JSON.parse(response) and alert it, and see if you are getting a valid JSON.

Comment: In your onchange...is javascrip a thing?